# Opening and closing a log file leads to memory leaks in C

Tags: c, valgrind, glib, gstring

Debugging a legacy code. I have a program written in C. it's actually much longer but I have created a small reproducible program to show the issues (please ignore the fact that this program does not make a lot of sense). The program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define FILE_SEP "/"
#define LENGTH 10

FILE *log_file;
char TMP[LENGTH];
char RESULT_DIRECTORY[LENGTH + 12];

int open_log() {
    GString *path = g_string_new(RESULT_DIRECTORY);
    g_string_append(path, FILE_SEP);
    g_string_append(path, TMP);
    g_string_append(path,".usr");
    log_file = fopen(path->str,"w");
    if (!log_file)
        return 1;
    
    return 0;
}

void close_log() {
    fclose(log_file);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    strcpy(TMP, "tmp");
    strcpy(RESULT_DIRECTORY, "/home/");
    if (open_log()) {
        return 1;
    }
    close_log();
    return 0;
}
```

Running valgrind I get:

```
> valgrind --tool=memcheck --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes program
==84011== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==84011== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==84011== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==84011== Command: c_status_reader
==84011== 
==84011== 
==84011== HEAP SUMMARY:
==84011==     in use at exit: 5,292 bytes in 9 blocks
==84011==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 1 frees, 5,860 bytes allocated
==84011== 
==84011== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 7
==84011==    at 0x4C29104: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==84011==    by 0x4C29278: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:785)
==84011==    by 0x5078ABD: g_realloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x5092B13: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x5093C99: g_string_sized_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x5093D14: g_string_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x108BE0: open_log (program.c:21)
==84011==    by 0x108A6E: main (program.c:40)
==84011== 
==84011== 252 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 7
==84011==    at 0x4C27393: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==84011==    by 0x5078B39: g_malloc0 (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x508CCE2: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x508EB5C: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x5093C6A: g_string_sized_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x5093D14: g_string_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x108BE0: open_log (program.c:21)
==84011==    by 0x108A6E: main (program.c:40)
==84011== 
==84011== 496 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 3 of 7
==84011==    at 0x4C2710E: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:858)
==84011==    by 0x4C271A9: posix_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:1021)
==84011==    by 0x508D4B0: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x508ECE2: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x5093C6A: g_string_sized_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x5093D14: g_string_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x108BE0: open_log (program.c:21)
==84011==    by 0x108A6E: main (program.c:40)
==84011== 
==84011== 504 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 7
==84011==    at 0x4C27393: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==84011==    by 0x5078B39: g_malloc0 (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x508CCC3: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x508EB5C: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x5093C6A: g_string_sized_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x5093D14: g_string_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x108BE0: open_log (program.c:21)
==84011==    by 0x108A6E: main (program.c:40)
==84011== 
==84011== 504 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 7
==84011==    at 0x4C27393: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==84011==    by 0x5078B39: g_malloc0 (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x508CD2A: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x508EB5C: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x5093C6A: g_string_sized_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x5093D14: g_string_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x108BE0: open_log (program.c:21)
==84011==    by 0x108A6E: main (program.c:40)
==84011== 
==84011== 1,488 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 6 of 7
==84011==    at 0x4C2710E: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:858)
==84011==    by 0x4C271A9: posix_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:1021)
==84011==    by 0x508D4B0: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x508ED22: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x5093C6A: g_string_sized_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x5093D14: g_string_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x108BE0: open_log (program.c:21)
==84011==    by 0x108A6E: main (program.c:40)
==84011== 
==84011== 2,032 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 7 of 7
==84011==    at 0x4C27393: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==84011==    by 0x5078B39: g_malloc0 (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x508EB12: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x5093C6A: g_string_sized_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x5093D14: g_string_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==84011==    by 0x108BE0: open_log (program.c:21)
==84011==    by 0x108A6E: main (program.c:40)
==84011== 
==84011== LEAK SUMMARY:
==84011==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==84011==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==84011==      possibly lost: 2,000 bytes in 5 blocks
==84011==    still reachable: 3,292 bytes in 4 blocks
==84011==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==84011== 
==84011== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==84011== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 5)
```

I think that I understand the problem - it's missing the `g_string_free` call somewhere. But, when I actually use it, it says: `still reachable: 5,276 bytes in 8 blocks`. For example I have only the following `open_log` (and without calling `close_log`):

```
int open_log() {
    GString *path = g_string_new(RESULT_DIRECTORY);
    g_string_append(path, FILE_SEP);
    g_string_free(path,TRUE);
    //log_file = fopen(path->str,"w");
    //if (!log_file)
    //    return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
==88254==
==88254== LEAK SUMMARY:
==88254==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==88254==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==88254==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==88254==    still reachable: 5,276 bytes in 8 blocks
==88254==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

But, if I remove `g_string_append(path, FILE_SEP);` then it actually works! So I'm guessing, when I do `g_string_free`, it only removes the initial string `path` and not the append part. Is it correct? How can I solve the issues?

**EDIT**:

Actually the first think I tried was to add `g_string_free(path, TRUE);` after the `fopen`, but I still see memory leaks. The code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<glib.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


#define FILE_SEP "/"
#define LENGTH 10

FILE *log_file;
char TMP[LENGTH];
char RESULT_DIRECTORY[LENGTH + 12];

int open_log(void) {
    GString *path = g_string_new(RESULT_DIRECTORY);
    g_string_append(path, FILE_SEP);
    g_string_append(path, TMP);
    g_string_append(path, ".usr");
    log_file = fopen(path->str, "w");
    g_string_free(path, TRUE);
    
    if (!log_file)
        return 1;
    
    return 0;
}

void close_log() {
    if (log_file) {
        fclose(log_file);
        log_file = NULL;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    strcpy(TMP, "tmp");
    strcpy(RESULT_DIRECTORY, "/home/");
    if (open_log()) {
        return 1;
    }
    close_log();
    return 0;
}
```

The valgrind output:

```
==23525== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==23525== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==23525== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==23525== Command: c_status_reader
==23525== 
==23525== 
==23525== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23525==     in use at exit: 5,276 bytes in 8 blocks
==23525==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 2 frees, 5,860 bytes allocated
==23525== 
==23525== 252 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 6
==23525==    at 0x4C27393: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==23525==    by 0x5078B39: g_malloc0 (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x508CCE2: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x508EB5C: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x5093C6A: g_string_sized_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x5093D14: g_string_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x108C31: open_log (program.c:21)
==23525==    by 0x108ABC: main (program.c:45)
==23525== 
==23525== 496 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 6
==23525==    at 0x4C2710E: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:858)
==23525==    by 0x4C271A9: posix_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:1021)
==23525==    by 0x508D4B0: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x508ECE2: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x5093C6A: g_string_sized_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x5093D14: g_string_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x108C31: open_log (program.c:21)
==23525==    by 0x108ABC: main (program.c:45)
==23525== 
==23525== 504 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 6
==23525==    at 0x4C27393: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==23525==    by 0x5078B39: g_malloc0 (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x508CCC3: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x508EB5C: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x5093C6A: g_string_sized_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x5093D14: g_string_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x108C31: open_log (program.c:21)
==23525==    by 0x108ABC: main (program.c:45)
==23525== 
==23525== 504 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 6
==23525==    at 0x4C27393: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==23525==    by 0x5078B39: g_malloc0 (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x508CD2A: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x508EB5C: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x5093C6A: g_string_sized_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x5093D14: g_string_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x108C31: open_log (program.c:21)
==23525==    by 0x108ABC: main (program.c:45)
==23525== 
==23525== 1,488 bytes in 3 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 6
==23525==    at 0x4C2710E: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:858)
==23525==    by 0x4C271A9: posix_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:1021)
==23525==    by 0x508D4B0: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x508ED22: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x5093C6A: g_string_sized_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x5093D14: g_string_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x108C31: open_log (program.c:21)
==23525==    by 0x108ABC: main (program.c:45)
==23525== 
==23525== 2,032 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 6
==23525==    at 0x4C27393: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==23525==    by 0x5078B39: g_malloc0 (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x508EB12: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x5093C6A: g_string_sized_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x5093D14: g_string_new (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5)
==23525==    by 0x108C31: open_log (program.c:21)
==23525==    by 0x108ABC: main (program.c:45)
==23525== 
==23525== LEAK SUMMARY:
==23525==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23525==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23525==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23525==    still reachable: 5,276 bytes in 8 blocks
==23525==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23525== 
==23525== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==23525== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 5)
```

Why it didn't solve it? I even tries to set `path` as global var and call the `g_string_free` in the `close_log` function. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Your first assumption is right, you do not call `g_string_free` neither in `open_log` nor in `close_log`, thus you get a memory leak.

As for

> But, when I actually use it, it says: `still reachable: 5,276 bytes in 8 blocks.`.  For example I have only the following `open_log` (and without calling `close_log`):

The last sentence in the quote is the answer. You do not call `close_log`, thus the `FILE *log_file` leaks now.

> if I remove `g_string_append(path, FILE_SEP);` then it actually works!

If you remove `g_string_append` then `log_file = fopen(path->str,"w");` is unable to open a file because it is a directory, `fopen` returns `NULL` and nothing leaks.

If you keep getting memory leaks after all fixes, then you see valgrind's false positive reports regarding glib internal stuff. The glib developers were so kind that they provided the special file for suppressing such false positive reports in valgrinds:

```
/usr/share/glib-2.0/valgrind/glib.supp
```

This path may vary, look for `glib.supp`, use the command `locate valgrind/glib.supp`. Use the file with valgrind:

```
valgrind --suppressions=/usr/share/glib-2.0/valgrind/glib.supp <...>
```

Comment: Can you post a full code of the program that doesn't leak because I tried to reproduce OP's issues and I get the same results that is valgrind still reports some _still reachable_ (unless you do not consider this a leak)?

Comment: @273K Yes, I understand that `g_string_free` is missing, but when I tried to add it right after the `fopen` it didn't work and I still got leaks. This made me go try other stuff that I mention. As I understand, you suggest to add `g_string_free` but even if I put it right after `fopen` or in `close_log` (and make `path` global) it still does not work. Makes me wonder if it's a problem with the library.

Comment: @vesii See the update in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`path` is allocated with `g_string_new` in `open_log()`, but it is not freed nor stored elsewhere before the function returns, hence causing a memory leak.

Free this string with `g_string_free` before returning:

```
int open_log(void) {
    GString *path = g_string_new(RESULT_DIRECTORY);
    g_string_append(path, FILE_SEP);
    g_string_append(path, TMP);
    g_string_append(path, ".usr");
    log_file = fopen(path->str, "w");
    g_string_free(path, TRUE);

    if (!log_file)
        return 1;
    
    return 0;
}
```

For cleanliness I would recommend setting `log_file` to `NULL` after it is closed:

```
void close_log(void) {
    if (log_file) {
        fclose(log_file);
        log_file = NULL;
    }
}
```

This should fix the block no longer accessible problem, but there may be some blocks allocated by the Glib for its own bookkeeping or by a successful call to `fopen` still lingering for Valgrind to report.

**EDIT**: after fixing the memory leak, there are still 8 blocks allocated and reachable when the program exits: these blocks are all allocated by `g_string_new` probably for ancillary data in the GLib string package.  This package is known to have [some issues with valgrind](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=gtk-list@gnome.org&q=subject:%22Memory%20Leak%5C%3F%22&o=newest&f=1), there might be ways to reduce the noise, but you can ignore these blocks for you purpose.

Using the GLib for just this purpose is not necessary. To avoid its side effects, here is an alternative:

```
int open_log(void) {
    char path[1024];
    snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s%s%s.usr",
             RESULT_DIRECTORY, FILE_SEP, TMP);
    log_file = fopen(path, "w");
    if (!log_file)
        return 1;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This was the first thing that I tried. But It still shows `still reachable: 5,276 bytes in 8 blocks`. I even tried to copy-paste your answer.  Please consider my edit.

Comment: @vesii: these blocks are internal data allocated by `g_string_new`. You can ignore them. I amended the answer with extra explanations.

Comment: Thanks! If I call for example `g_string_sized_new` without adding actual string afterwards with `g_string_append`. Do I need to call `g_string_free`? Because when I do, it says I have a possible memory leak and when I don't it says "still reachable".